# Android Developers: How to bypass WPS when using WifiP2p

Tags: java, android, wifip2p, wps

I was searching a way to bypass the WPS dialog while two devices are connecting via wifi p2p. Right now, everytime when two devices are trying to connect with each other, I have to choose one of the WPS methods. Yet I don't want any of these.
I am aiming to connect multiple device via wifip2p without notify users, as long as they are running my program. 
PS: only via wifip2p, not via Wifi.
Please, any help will be great.

Comment: Looks like you'd better show the related code so that others can point what to modify and how